# C: writing the following code into functions

Tags: c

Dear respected programmers. Please could you help me (again) on how to put the following code into functions for my program.
I have read on-line and understand how functions work but when I do it myself it all goes pear shaped/wrong(I am such a noob).
Please could you help with how to for example to  write the code below into functions.(like opening the input file).

---

My initial code looks like:

```
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
 int bytes_read, bytes_written;
 struct stat inode;
 int input_fd, output_fd;
 char buffer[64];
 int eof = 0;
 int i;

 /* Check the command line arguments */
 if (argc != 3) 
 {
   printf("syntax is:         %s \n", <fromfile> <tofile>\n", argv[0]);
  exit (1);
 }

 /* Check the input file exists and is a file */
 if ((stat(argv[1], &inode) == -1) || (!S_ISREG(inode.st_mode)))
 {
  printf("%s is not a file\n", argv[1]);
  exit(2);
 }

 /* Check that the output file doesnt exist */
 if (stat(argv[2], &inode) != -1)
 {
  printf("Warning: The file %s already exists. Not going to overwrite\n", argv[2]);
  exit(2);
 }

 /* Open the input file for reading */
 input_fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY, 0);
 if (input_fd == -1)
 {
  printf("%s cannot be opened\n", argv[1]);
  exit(3);
 }

 output_fd = open(argv[2], O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_EXCL , S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
 if (output_fd == -1)
 {
  printf("%s cannot be opened\n", argv[2]);
  exit(3);
 }

 /* Begin processing the input file here */
 while (!eof)
 {
  bytes_read = read(input_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

  if (bytes_read == -1)
  {
   printf("%s cannot be read\n", argv[1]);
   exit(4);
  }

  if (bytes_read > > 0)
  {
   bytes_written = write(output_fd, buffer, bytes_read);
   if (bytes_written == -1)
   {
    printf("There was an error writing to the file %s\n",argv[2]);
    exit(4);
   }

   if (bytes_written != bytes_read)
   {
    printf("Devistating failure! Bytes have either magically appeared and been written or dissapeard and been skipped.  Data is inconsistant!\n");
    exit(101);
   }
  } 
  else
  {
   eof = 1;
  }
 }
   close(input_fd);
 close(output_fd);

}
```

---

My attempt at opening an output file:

```
void outputFile(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    /* Check that the output file doesnt exist */

    if (stat(argv[argc-1], &inode) != -1)
    {
        printf("Warning: The file %s already exists. Not going to overwrite\n", argv[argc-1]); 
        return -1;
    }

    /*Opening ouput files*/

    file_desc_out = open(argv[i],O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_EXCL , S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
    if(file_desc_out == -1)
    {
        printf("Error: %s cannot be opened. \n",argv[i]);           //insted of argv[2] have pointer i. 
        return -1;
    }
}
```

---

Any help on how I would now reference to this in my program is appreciated thank you.
I tried:
ouputfile (but I cant figure out what goes here and why either).

Comment: You are using stat and low level calls and you don't know how to write function?

Comment: Show us what you've got, and we'll give you advice on avoiding a pear shape.  We generally don't just do homework for people.

Comment: But I dont know how to do functions any advice on how I could go about doing them. taskinoor yes I dont know how to write function even though I can do that.

Comment: OK I will post my attempt thanks.

Comment: @donok:  If this is homework, you have been taught how to write functions, or the information is somehow available to you.  Try it.  Write what you've got above as a function and post it.  It doesn't really matter how bad you screw it up.  That way we'll see some effort on your part, and we'll have specific things to critique.

Comment: @donok:  Thanks for cooperating with us.  You should do all right here.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the most useful function for you is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

extern void error_exit(int rc, const char *format, ...);  /* In a header */

void error_exit(int rc, const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vfprintf(stderr, format, args);
    va_end(args);
    exit(rc);
}
```

You can then write:

```
if (stat(argv[2], &inode) != -1)
    error_exit(2, "Warning: The file %s exists. Not going to overwrite\n",
              argv[2]);
```

Which has the merit of brevity.

You write functions to do sub-tasks.  Deciding where to break up your code into functions is tricky - as much art as science.  Your code is not so big that it is completely awful to leave it as it is - one function (though the error handling can be simplified as above).

If you want to practice writing functions, consider splitting it up:

- `open_input_file()`
- `open_output_file()`
- `checked_read()`
- `checked_write()`
- `checked_close()`

These functions would allow your main code to be written as:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int bytes_read;
    int input_fd, output_fd;
    char buffer[64];

    if (argc != 3) 
         error_exit(1, "Usage: %s <fromfile> <tofile>\n", argv[0]);

    input_fd  = open_input_file(argv[1]);
    output_fd = open_output_file(argv[2]);

    while ((bytes_read = checked_read(input_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) > 0)
        check_write(output_fd, buffer, bytes_read);

    checked_close(input_fd);
    checked_close(output_fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Because you've tucked the error handling out of sight, it is now much easier to see the structure of the program.  If you don't have enough functions yet, you can bury the loop into a function `void file_copy(int fd_in, int fd_out)`.  That removes more clutter from `main()` and leaves you with very simple code.

---

Given an initial attempt at a function to open the output file:

```
void outputFile(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    /* Check that the output file doesnt exist */

    if (stat(argv[argc-1], &inode) != -1)
    {
        printf("Warning: The file %s already exists. Not going to overwrite\n", argv[argc-1]); 
        return -1;
    }

    /*Opening ouput files*/

    file_desc_out = open(argv[i],O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_EXCL , S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
    if(file_desc_out == -1)
    {
        printf("Error: %s cannot be opened. \n",argv[i]);           //insted of argv[2] have pointer i. 
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Critique:

- You have to define the variables used by the function in the function (you will want to avoid global variables as much as possible, and there is no call for any global variable in this code).
- You have to define the return type.  You are opening a file - how is the file descriptor going to be returned to the calling code?  So, the return type should be `int`.
- You pass only the information needed to the function - a simple form of 'information hiding'.  In this case, you only need to pass the name of the file; the information about file modes and the like is implicit in the name of the function.
- In general, you have to decide how to handle errors.  Unless you have directives otherwise from your homework setter, it is reasonable to exit on error with an appropriate message.  If you return an error indicator, then the calling code has to test for it, and decide what to do about the error.
- Errors and warnings should be written to `stderr`, not to `stdout`.  The main program output (if any) goes to `stdout`.
- Your code is confused about whether `argv[i]` or `argv[argc-1]` is the name of the output file.  In a sense, this criticism is irrelevant once you pass just the filename to the function.  However, consistency is a major virtue in programming, and using the same expression to identify the same thing is usually a good idea.
- Consistency of layout is also important.  Don't use both `if(` and `if (` in your programs; use the canonical `if (` notation as used by the language's founding fathers, K&R.
- Similarly, be consistent with no spaces before commas, a space after a comma, and be consistent with spaces around operators such as '`|`'.  Consistency makes your code easier to read, and you'll be reading your code a lot more often than you write it (at least, once you've finished your course, you will do more reading than writing).
- You cannot have `return -1;` inside a function that returns no value.

When you a splitting up code into functions, you need to copy/move the paragraphs of code that you are extracting, leaving behind a call to the new function.  You also need to copy the relevant local variables from the calling function into the new function - possibly eliminating the variables in the calling function if they are no longer used there.  You do compile with most warnings enabled, don't you?  You want to know about unused variables etc.

When you create the new function, one of the most important parts is working out what the correct signature of the function is.  Does it return a value?  If so, which value, and what is its type?  If not, how does it handle errors?  In this case, you probably want the function to bail out (terminate the program) if it runs into an error.  In bigger systems, you might need to consistently return an error indicator (0 implies success, negative implies failure, different negatives indicating different errors).  When you work with function that return an error indicator, it is almost always crucial that you check the error indicators in the calling code.  For big programs, big swathes of the code can be all about error handling.  Similarly, you need to work out which values are passed into the function.

I'm omitting advice about things such as 'be const correct' as overkill for your stage in learning to program in C.

Comment: I cant thank you more for your help, I will go and experiment for the next few hours.

Answer (score 1):

There's several things.

The function return type isn't what you want.  You either want to return a file descriptor or an error code.  IIRC, the file descriptor is a nonnegative `int`, so you can use a return type of `int` rather than `void`.  You also need to return something on either path, either -1 or `file_desc_out`.

You probably don't want to pass in the command-line arguments as a whole, but rather something like `argv[argc - 1]`.  In that case, the argument should be something like `char * filename` rather than the argc/argv it has now.  (Note that the `argv[i]` you've got in the last `printf` is almost certainly wrong.)

This means it would be called something like

```
int file_desc_out = outputFile(argv[argc - 1]);
```

You need to have all variables declared in the function, specifically `inode` and `file_desc_out`.

Finally, put an extra level of indentation on the code inside the `{` and `}` of the function itself.

Answer (score 1):

you seem to actually understand how to make a function. making a function really isnt that hard. first, you need to kind of understand that a function has a type. in otherwords, argc has type `int` and argv has type `char *`, your function (currently) has type `void`. void means it has no value, which means when you return, you return nothing.
however, if you look at your code, you do `return -1`. it looks like you want to return an interger. so you should change the top from `void outputfile(...)` to `int outputfile(...)`.
next, your function must return. it wont compile if there is a circumstance where it won't return (besides infinite loops). so at the very bottom, if no errors happen, it will reach the end. since you're no longer using "void" as the return type, you must return something before the end of the function. so i suggest putting a `return 1;` to show that everything went great